# XCode 7 Swift - Call can throw, it it is not markedwith 'try' and the error is not handled

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation

I'm trying to play music on my iOS application when I click a button and I already know how to do it but this time when I insert the line; `audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioPlayerURL, error: nil)`it will give me an option to change `error`to `fileTypeHint`which I do but then I get the following error; `Call can throw, it it is not markedwith 'try' and the error is not handled'.

I don't really understand because in `Xcode 6` I used the word `error` in that line of code and I had no issues with that and playing music was working. There must be a different or similar way of writing that line since I've upgraded to Xcode 7 Beta 3 but I've searched everywhere to see what's changed.

Would anybody know anything about it?

Comment: See [Error Handling in Swift 2.0](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/error-handling-in-swift-2/).  Particularly the part about *Interacting with the Cocoa and Cocoa Touch Frameworks*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, after piecing together some information this is what I came up with and it works in Swift 2.0.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {

    let bgMusicURL:NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("bgmusic", withExtension: "mp3")!

    backgroundMusicPlayer = try!  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL)

    backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1

    backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()

    backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
}
```

Make sure to Import AVFoundation

and also add this in your controller

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

Comment: (1) I would avoid using `try!` because it will crash your app if there's an error (2) this code will get repeated every time the view's size changes because you put it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`; I would avoid that. (3) There is no purpose to calling `prepareToPlay()` immediately before `play()`

Comment: Okay...
1a) If I remove    try! Xcode barks at me and gives the following error.
Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled.
1b) If I change     try! to    try Xcode barks at me and give the following error.
Errors thrown from here are not handled.
2) Moved to viewDidLoad..thanks.
3) Removed prepareToPlay()...thanks.

Comment: You should use `do { let x = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL) } catch { // handle error }`

Answer (score 3):

Error handling has changed in Swift 2.0. Use the following try-catch code to resolve the error:

```
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: audioFileUrl,
                                        fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeMPEGLayer3)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("AV Sound Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```